# Easy graphical editor for Dialog Box Styles (Windows)

Tags: c, dialog, styles, box

I am working on a very Big and old C code. The windows for GUI are designed with Dialog Box Styles (Windows) in a resource file(*.rc). one simple window in this code is designed like this:

```
ID_DIALOGEX 0, 0, 264, 197
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    EDITTEXT        IDC_NAME_ORG,83,39,174,14,ES_AUTOHSCROLL
    EDITTEXT        IDC_NAME_REF,83,57,174,14,ES_AUTOHSCROLL
    LTEXT           "Name for field 1:",IDC_STATIC,7,41,73,8
    LTEXT           "Name for field 2:",IDC_STATIC,7,60,73,8
    COMBOBOX        IDC_SAVEBIG_FIELD,84,157,144,42,CBS_DROPDOWNLIST | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
    LTEXT           "Data field:",IDC_STATIC,35,158,34,8
    EDITTEXT        IDC_NAME_XMIN,83,76,174,14,ES_AUTOHSCROLL
    EDITTEXT        IDC_NAME_XMAX,83,95,174,14,ES_AUTOHSCROLL
    LTEXT           "Name for x-axis min:",IDC_STATIC,7,79,73,8
    LTEXT           "Name for x-axis max:",IDC_STATIC,7,98,73,8
    EDITTEXT        IDC_NAME_YMIN,83,113,174,14,ES_AUTOHSCROLL
    EDITTEXT        IDC_NAME_YMAX,83,131,174,14,ES_AUTOHSCROLL
    LTEXT           "Name for y-axis min:",IDC_STATIC,7,115,73,8
    LTEXT           "Name for y-axis max:",IDC_STATIC,7,135,73,8
    CTEXT           "don't save the info",IDC_STATIC,34,9,194,25
    CONTROL         "Use zlib compression",IDC_SAVE_CBX_ZIP,"Button",BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | WS_TABSTOP,91,177,81,10
END
```

the 4 numbers after each line are the x,y,width andh height. So it is pretty exhausting to edit a window like this. I wanted to know is there a easy graphical designer that can produce code like this?

Comment: Visual C from Microsoft still handles this format.

Comment: Just google "windows resource editor .rc"

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I coulnt find it. can u send me a link?

Comment: What about the first result of google http://www.resedit.net/ ?

Comment: Alternatively, just use the Visual C++ community edition - it is from MS and it is free.  You can do all your development in it.

Comment: @KeineLust Tried it. It's not real.#

Comment: @cup I can not make any changes to VS, because the system is shared. any other suggestions?

Comment: If you use VS, all you need is a dummy project.  Overwrite the dummy rc with your rc file.  Do all your edits and then write it back.  You don't have to use it for development: just for visualizing and editing your forms.